# What is the official SE stance on proposing an exchange just for the sake of having the proposal?

Tags: discussion, support, area-51, site-proposal

I currently have one proposal that is really of great interest to me. But I have another idea or two that (as of the writing of this anyway), don't exist. And I really don't care if they take off or not - I would like them to, but if they die at any point in the process, no big deal. Even if they go to beta, I personally might or might not be involved (it depends on how busy I am if/when they go beta).

Would proposing them be in line with/against what Area 51 and the Stack Exchange idea is?

Answer (score 5):

Have you seen some of the crap that has been proposed so far?  It seems that anything goes.  If it's blatantly offensive, it will get closed.  If it's lame, it will get ignored.  If it catches the public's fancy, you might be on to something.

It can't hurt to try.  Run it up the flagpole and see who salutes.

Comment: Hmm. I guess I'll think of a good title/description to kind of solidify it, throw it against the wall, and see if it sticks...unless one of the SE team members says otherwise before I get around to that.